# Array and string in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, typecasting-operator

Hi amazing stackers!

```
date = "10/02/2021"
d1 = date.split("/")
d2 = d1.to_s
puts d1
puts d1.class
puts d2
puts d2.class
```

in the above code, d2 shows the data type "string" but it is displayed like an array. And d1 is an array but it doesn't have an array like form. Can you please resolve the confusion?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are expecting

```
date = "10/02/2021"
d1 = date.split("/")
d2 = d1.join
p "--------------------------"
p d1
p d1.class
p d2
p d2.class
p "--------------------------"
```

Output

```
"--------------------------"
["10", "02", "2021"]
Array
"10022021"
String
"--------------------------"
```

Use `p` instead `puts`, it will print the data along with it's structure. Use `join` to combine the array element into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the documentation for the full details but

[Array#to_s](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-inspect) creates a string representation of the array by calling inspect on each element.  Basically this creates a string that looks the way you would expect an array to look if you inspected it, ie `p d2`.

[IO#puts](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-i-puts) when called with an array as the argument writes each element on a new line.